# How to retrieve custom html attribute in php POST?

Tags: php, html, post

I have a custom Checkbox its made in a Div

```
<div class="zs" name="toggle" state="on" id="zs"></div>
```

The checkbox has toggle on/off and the state attribute changes on click to on/off.

The div is placed in a  for submittion but I dont know how to get $_POST['toggle'] from php to receive the attribute "state"

Comment: Adding a `name` attribute doesn't make a `div` a form element... You'll have to either build the POST with javascript (in which case we want to see that code), or use a plain old checkbox (remember you can have a big label for that checkbox, so formatting-wise there are a lot of options).

Comment: I wanted to avoid using Ajax request to build the POST. Is there another way?

Comment: Not if you abuse a `div` for this. Really, a `label` with a `for` attribute and a hidden `<input type="checkbox">` seems the way to go here if you don't want to manually build the post. Or update an `<input type="hidden">` somewhere.

Comment: Div is not a valid form element so you cannot POST information in its attributes anywhere, even if the div is surrounded by FORM tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is only going to send through `input` and `select` tags with the form submission, not `div`.  It sounds like you might want to store your value in a hidden `input`, IE:

```
<input type='hidden' name='toggle' value='on' />
```

Then add to whatever javascript you're already using to set the value appropriately.