# Posting MySQL data associated with PHP populated drop down menu

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a pretty particular question and cannot seem to find any resources on the subject. Last time I posted the community was a great help. Hopefully this time it will be as well.

I am trying to post information from a drop down menu that is populated with information from a mysql database. I want to post this info back to the same database, but into a different table. I am also looking to post a different piece of information then what is being displayed in the drop down menu.

For example;

My form has a "venues" field on it:

```
      <tr>
        <td>Venue:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="venue">
                <?php query_venue() ?>
            </select>                   
        </td>
      </tr>
```

This field is populated with an array from my database using the following PHP function:

```
   function query_venue(){
$venue=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_db.venues");
while($venue_record = mysql_fetch_array($venue)){
   echo '<option value="'. $venue_record['name'] . '">' . $venue_record['name'] . '</options>';
  }
}
```

Now what I am looking to do is upon someone hitting the "submit" button on the form I want to execute a `$_PUT` function to send not the value from the `'name'` column that was selected, but instead the `'venue_id'` from the same row of the name that was selected to my `my_db.events` table.
I believe the function would look like this, I just do not know how to change the drop down menu from sending the `'name'` field to sending the `'venue_id'` field:

```
 function put_venue_id(){
 $venue_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['venue']);
 mysql_query = "INSERT INTO my_db.events (venue_id)
 VALUES ('$venue_id')";
}
```

If anyone can shed light on this situation that would be awesome! I am just diving into relational databases and this is a fun step!
Thanks for the help folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set the option's `value` attribute to the `venue_id` and the value that is visible to the user to the `venue_name`:

```
echo '<option value="'. $venue_record['id'] . '">' . $venue_record['name'] . '</option>';
```

You could also do something with custom attributes or hidden fields:

[How to retrieve custom html attribute in php POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091649/how-to-retrieve-custom-html-attribute-in-php-post)

I hope this is useful in some way.

Comment: Perfect!! This is exactly what I was looking for thanks a ton. I am getting the Unique ID's instead of the names. Now if I could only figure out how to make my php stop feeding blank entries to the DB!? :S Thanks a bunch @Sjaak Rusma

Comment: No problem, could you accept my answer? And for the blank entries thing, you should `var_dump` the values when they are about to be inserted. Then you can figure out when it happens and possibly prevent that